# Can't replace one file with other

Tags: java, delete-file

So I have this piece of code that is supposed to swap the old file with new file (the old file already exists, and the new file gets generated in different method of the same class, but I tested it and it gets generated properly so the bug is not in the file), but for some reason, the file does not get renamed and the wrong one gets deleted. Been stuck with this over a hour now, any feedback is welcome.

```
 public static void replaceAndDelete() {

        String pathOLD = System.getProperty("user.home");
        pathOLD = pathOLD+"\\cd.txt";
        File fileOLD = new File(pathOLD);
        String pathNEW = System.getProperty("user.home");
        pathNEW = pathNEW+"\\temp.txt";
        File fileNEW = new File (pathNEW);
        fileNEW.renameTo(fileOLD);
        fileOLD.delete();



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are renaming `fileNEW` to `fileOLD` and then deleting the `fileOLD`. That means you're deleting the **path**, not the "virtual file" in the JVM memory.

The final code with some edit was:

```
String pathOLD = "C:\\test\\old.txt";
String pathNEW = "C:\\test\\new.txt";
File fileOLD = new File(pathOLD);
File fileNEW = new File (pathNEW);
fileOLD.delete();
fileNEW.renameTo(fileOLD);
```

Don't forget you're deleting the old one and renaming the new with the **old's name**. That means you should check the **inside** of the file, because I was also thinking it was deleting the wrong file while it was simply deleting and renaming correcly.

Comment: There is still some gremlin. The code you proposed does not delete the old file at all, and the contents of the new generated file are correct. The old file for example has 6 lines of text, the new file has only 5 lines, because one line was deleted in other method. After the code runs, both files are exactly the same as they were at the beginning.

Comment: That's really odd. Have you tried simulating the environment I proposed here with the C:\test folder for the sake of debugging? This solution worked like a peach here.

Comment: Me idiot, big idiot. The issue was unclosed buffered reader in method. So the file was left open and the program could not rename it. Thanks, you indirectly helped me to find my issue.

Comment: @TheLaw Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure resources (eg readers, writers, etc.) are closed instead of leaked when they are not needed. Windows (but not unix-based systems) can't modify files while they are in use. I expect that both the delete and the rename failed with the same exception. It is beneficial to include the exception in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these lines are not in the order you want:

```
fileNEW.renameTo(fileOLD);
fileOLD.delete();
```

Comment: Tried swapping those lines, still pretty much the same issue.